# Creating an custom mat-icon with Github SVG

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg, angular-material

Attempting to create a custom SVG `mat-icon` loading the SVG directly from Github.  I first tried this using the `DomSanitizer` and [documented the result in this article](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/using-github-as-a-cdn-for-angular-svg-content-4411c59651c5).  So the SVG does load via the `HttpClient`.

Now I'm trying to do it directly via the `DomSanitizer` like this:

```
  constructor (private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
          this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      "logo",
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fireflysemantics/logo/master/l1.svg"));
    }
```

And doing a rendering test in `app.component.html`:

```
<mat-icon>logo</mat-icon>
```

And there's no SVG showing up.  I'm assuming that the line:

```
this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fireflysemantics/logo/master/l1.svg"));
```

Should load the svg, but I don't see a request in the network tab.  Also if we just paste the raw URL into the browser address bar:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fireflysemantics/logo/master/l1.svg

The request does show up in the network tab as `l1.svg`.

Thoughts?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-custom-icon?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

### Update

The above Stackblitz includes the fix from the answer, so it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry in `app.component.html` must look as follows:

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="logo"></mat-icon>
```